# How can I sort by a custom field date in the WordPress calendar widget?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I'm using "Advanced Custom Fields" along with "Custom Post Type UI" to create events on my Wordpress site. Everything works fine and the templates are in place however I can't get the posts to display properly in the Wordpress calendar widget.

At the moment the posts are filtered by publishing date. However, for my purposes, I need them shown by the date of the event itself – not the day I created the post. I've already got a custom field called "event_date" that's stored in yymmdd format. With that said, is there a way to overwrite the default behavior of the calendar widget to sort by this field?

If not is there a plugin that might help me accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this add-on for the Advanced Custom Fields WordPress plugin:

http://wordpress.org/plugins/acf-field-date-time-picker/